# Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu hangs or freezes frequently

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gtk

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7.x) on Ubuntu 12.04 with sun hotspot java 6.

Eclipse freezes quite frequently (no specific pattern, just random).

The Ubuntu system profiler shows the process status as 100% cpu (1 core completely occupied - sometimes it shows as either 96 or 104%) and sleeping with futex_wait_queue_me as the waiting channel. I could infer from this as some kind of a loop keeping 1 core busy but doing nothing.

I took thread dumps using Visualvm everytime eclipse freezes. Each time, a thread in runnable state shows the below class/method at the top of the stack

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f490c008000 nid=0xe4b runnable [0x00007f4913aea000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_tree_store_set(Native Method)  at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_tree_store_set(OS.java:11841)   at 
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.setImage(TreeItem.java:1613)
```

The line at OS.java:11841 is as below (browsed from grepcode.com)

```
_gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func(tree_column, cell_renderer, func, func_data, destroy);
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It started after I updated ubuntu. Unfortunately I do not recall exactly what was updated.

Comment: Did you install Eclipse from Ubuntu Software Center or manual (from zip file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend updating Eclipse and Java, if possible. Another possibility is to downgrade Eclipse. A third possibility is to update the whole system to hopefully update a library file that could be buggy/faulty. A fourth guess of mine is that a plug-in may be causing the problem. My last guess is to update/downgrade GTK.

Comment: I've tried all upgrade options. The latest Indigo version seems to be less freezing, but the overall problem still persists. Not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 seems to have resolved this completely. I don't see the screen freezing anymore with Eclipse. Thanks Ubuntu!